# Image processing channels in LAB space

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to adjust the curves in LAB space as per screenshot of photoshop command below:

[image]

I am using this method:

```
img = ColorConvert[ImageResize[
Import["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503803548695-c2a7b4a5b875"], 400], "LAB"];
{l, a, b} = ColorSeparate[img, "LAB"];
Grid[{Show[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {img, ColorCombine[{l, 1.4 a, 1.4 b}, "LAB"]}}]
```

[image]

The results appear similar, but it seems like a bit of a naive workaround. Is this essentially equivalent, or is there a more correct way to approach the problem?

[YouTube tutorial in photoshop for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YB2eib59nrI)